# updatedb does not prune paths

Tags: debian, locate, updatedb

I have a timeshift user with backups in my `/home`. Every time after boot when I search for something with **locate**, all the timeshift directories are shown to me. To fix this issue, I added `/home/timeshift` to the `PRUNEPATHS` variable in `/etc/alternatives/updatedb`. I'm running Debian 10. On Arch I had the same issue and resolved it by adding the path to `/etc/updatedb.conf`. On Debian I don't have this file, so I changed `/etc/alternatives/updatedb`.

When running `updatedb` manually after boot, `locate` doesn't show me the `PRUNEPATHS` anymore.
But when I first start the system, `updatedb` shows me my `/home/timeshift`. Changing `PRUNEPATHS` in `/etc/cron.daily/locate` does not help either.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/alternatives/updatedb` is a symbolic link to the actual `updatedb` script/binary of the `locate` variant that is currently in use on your system. If you edit it, the changes will be applied through the link to the actual `/usr/bin/updatedb.<variantname>` script... and whenever the `locate` package is updated, the package management will overwrite that script and **your changes will be lost**.

(There are two variants of `locate` in Debian 10: `locate` and `mlocate`. If you have both installed, then the `/etc/alternatives` mechanism will be used to determine which one will be used. The system administrator can use `update-alternatives --config locate` to switch the active variant.)

[Debian 10 also has a man page for `/etc/updatedb.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/mlocate/updatedb.conf.5.en.html), so if that file does not exist, you should just create it if you need non-default settings for `updatedb`.